# renaming uploaded file nodejs and multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

## problem with file name in Multer

i am using express.js and multer to upload images to server. i act like this:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, "../client/member/upload");
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            console.log('1', 1);
            callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
        }
    });
    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');
```

but the problem is that never file name changes.
my uploader handler:

```
function memberUpload(request, response) {

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, "../client/member/upload");
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            console.log('1', 1);
            callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
        }
    });
    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

    var folderName = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/member/upload');

    if (!fs.existsSync(folderName)) {
        fs.mkdir(folderName, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return response.status(500).send(err);
            }
            else {
                upload(request, response, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return response.status(400)
                            .send('No files were uploaded.');
                    }
                    var sentFile = request.files.file,
                        fileName = (request.files.file && request.files.file.name) ? request.files.file.name : 'test';

                    sentFile.mv(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/member/upload/', fileName), function (err) {
                        mime.lookup(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/member/upload/', fileName));         // => 'text/plain'
                        if (err) {
                            return response.status(500)
                                .send(err);
                        }
                        response.send({'location': '../member/upload/' + fileName});
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        upload(request, response, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return response.status(400)
                    .send('No files were uploaded.');
            }
            var sentFile = request.files.file,
                fileName = (request.files.file && request.files.file.name) ? request.files.file.name : 'test';

            sentFile.mv(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/member/upload/', fileName), function (err) {
                mime.lookup(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client/member/upload/', fileName));         // => 'text/plain'
                if (err) {
                    return response.status(500)
                        .send(err);
                }
                response.send({'location': '../member/upload/' + fileName});
            });
        });
    }
}
```

the file save into correct directory with name "blobid0.jpeg", "blobid1.png" and so on ...
what is my fault?

Comment: output object is: ```{ file:
   { name: 'blobid0.jpg',
     data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff ed 01 b8 50 68 6f 74 6f 73 68 6f 70 20 33 2e 30 00 38 42 49 4d 03 e9 00 00 00 00 00 78 ... >,
     encoding: '7bit',
     mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
     mv: [Function: mv] } }```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for uploading any file(pdf, txt, png) to server.Hope this will help you.

```
exports.saveMedia = ((req, res) => {
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, (config.const.path.base + config.const.path.productReviewMedia));
            },
            filename: (req, file, callback) => {
                callback(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);

            }
        });

        const upload = multer({storage: storage}).any('file');

        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: helper.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            }
            let results = req.files.map((file) => {
                return {
                    mediaName: file.filename,
                    origMediaName: file.originalname,
                    mediaSource: 'http://' + req.headers.host + config.const.path.productReviewMedia + file.filename
                }
            });
            res.status(200).json(results);
        });
    });
```